# Unknown interaction error with Discord.js v14 after cancelling and retrying a modal submit

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord bot that's using modals in Discord.js v14. These modals are shown after the user presses a button, and an `.awaitModalSubmit()` collector is called to take one modal submit interaction and perform some logic. This `.awaitModalSubmit()` uses a basic `filter` and `time` to only retrieve modal submit interactions within a time period (one minute) that are by the same user that initiated the interaction *and* have the correct `customId`.

Here's a simplified, reproducible version of my code:

```js
await interaction.showModal(
    new ModalBuilder()
        .setTitle("Echo Modal")
        .setCustomId("echomodal")
        .setComponents([
            new ActionRowBuilder<TextInputBuilder>().addComponents([
                new TextInputBuilder()
                    .setCustomId("echomodaltext")
                    .setLabel("Echo Text")
                    .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short),
            ]),
        ])
);

const result = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
    filter: async (i) => {
        await i.deferReply();
        return i.user.id === interaction.user.id && i.customId === "echomodal";
    },
    time: 60_000,
});

await result.editReply(result.fields.getTextInputValue("echomodaltext"));
```

This works great, until the user presses the **Cancel** button on a modal in Discord:

[image: The Discord modal cancel button]

After doing so, if I show a modal again **within the time period** of one minute, and this time I *submit* data, it still works but I get an uncaught exception error log:

```
Error: DiscordAPIError[10062] - Unknown interaction
```

Then, after the time period of a minute after my first interaction (the cancelled one), I get this error log:

```
Error: Error [InteractionCollectorError] - Collector received no interactions before ending with reason: time
```

It seems to me like the collector isn't being stopped when the user cancels a modal submission, leading to these errors. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured out what the issue is thanks to [this](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/7431#issuecomment-1046331835) comment from the Discord.js GitHub.

Cancelling a modal submission doesn't send any interactions to the modal submit collector, so a second modal submit interaction done after the first cancelled one is still satisfying the first collector's filter, so both the first collector and the second collector will attempt to handle the interaction.

Below is the modified code that uses the interaction's unique ID to create the modal's custom ID and filters on that:

```js
await interaction.showModal(
    new ModalBuilder()
        .setTitle("Echo Modal")
        .setCustomId(`modal_${interaction.id}`)
        .setComponents([
            new ActionRowBuilder<TextInputBuilder>().addComponents([
                new TextInputBuilder()
                    .setCustomId("echomodaltext")
                    .setLabel("Echo Text")
                    .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short),
            ]),
        ])
);
const result = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
    filter: async (i) => {
        const filter =
            i.user.id === interaction.user.id &&
            i.customId === `modal_${interaction.id}`;
        if (filter) {
            await i.deferReply();
        }
        return filter;
    },
    time: 10_000,
});

await result.editReply(result.fields.getTextInputValue("echomodaltext"));
```

This removes the `Unknown interaction` error log. The `InteractionCollectorError` timeout error will still be thrown, but you can catch that and do with it as you please (I've opted to just discard it).

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue as me.